# PHP: Best Practices for Silent Failure

Tags: php

I find myself doing this a lot:

```
$something = @$_GET['else'];
if ($something) {
    // ...
} else {
    // ...
}
```

Like, almost whenever I deal with arrays. I'm used to JavaScript and the ability to simply check for a falsy value. But is this appropriate in PHP? Am I trying to force PHP to be something I already understand, instead of learning it as its own language?

**EDIT**

I udnerstand that I can just use `isset` (I also *under*stand it), but it feels clunky to me, and it leads to even clunkier situations where I'm trying to echo the value:

```
// what I want to do
echo '<input type="text" name="whatever" value="', @$values['whatever'], '" />';

// what I fear I must do
echo '<input type="text" name="whatever" value="';
if (isset($values['whatever'])) {
    echo $values['whatever'];
}
echo '" />';
```

Setting aside the sanitation issue, I prefer the first version. But I have a sneaking suspiscion that it's a big no-no. (I also have a sneaking suspicion that I don't know how to spell "suspicion.")

Comment: Regarding your edit:  I think what you want to do is just fine.  A nonexistent `$values['whatever']` will come out as null and be cast into a null string.  The scope of error suppression is limited enough that it's not going to hide an error that you need to see.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I recommend **NEVER** using the @ operator. It encourages bad code and can make your life miserable when something doesn't work and you're trying to debug it.

You can of course disable notices in php.ini, but if I were you I would start using isset() more :)

You can do something like this:

```
echo '<input type="text" name="whatever" value="', (isset($values['whatever'])?$values['whatever']:''), '" />';
```

You can read more about how horrible `@` is, here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

Well, it's the actual error triggering that is expensive. Using @ triggers the error. Checking with isset() instead, does not. http://seanmonstar.com/post/909029460/php-error-suppression-performance

Comment: that is true, i had that kind of problem today when doing @$_GET[sef::VAR_NAME] and php wouldn't tell me what i was doing wrong (self not sef!!!).

Comment: Hi Fabio - If you're referencing an instance variable inside your PHP class, you'll want to use this: $myValue = $this->VAR_NAME; To go along with posters above, this would suffice: $myValue = (isset($_GET[$this->VAR_NAME])) ? $_GET[$this->VAR_NAME] : 'empty string';

Comment: The SELF keyword would be used to reference a static function in your PHP class (ie SELF::quote_string('quote this');)

Comment: I used to use `isset`, but then I discovered the `@` trick and went crazy with it. Just from a performance perspective, is calling a function better than suppressing errors?

Comment: `@` has little influence on the "performance". It's the undefined array offsets, if anything. And optimizing that is as senseful as using single quotes. Really, where do you people get those micro optimization fairy tales from?

Comment: @mario My mom had a giant book and read them to me as I was going to sleep when I was younger. "And the Big Bad Wolf said, 'I'll huff and I'll puff, and I'll unroll that loop, then use multiply/shift instead of division!' "

Comment: Well, it's the actual error triggering that is expensive. Using @ triggers the error. Checking with isset() instead, does not. http://seanmonstar.com/post/909029460/php-error-suppression-performance

Comment: @Jesse Bunch: Thanks for your concerns. I am using self::NAME_OF_A_CONSTANT, and don't see why I should make it an instance variable. But I am defenetively avoiding using the '@' again.

Comment: I often use !empty() as well as it covers falsey values, also (probably a more common use-case than the Javascript undefined scenario - i.e. if a GET variable is not present or is set to nothing, you probably want to do something else).  Not in every case!

Answer (score 7):

To answer the **title**: Best way is to [turn off `display_errors`](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors).

For what you're doing specifically, use [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php).

**Note:** To those complaining that this 'turns off' all errors -- [from the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors):

> This is a feature to support your development and should never be used on production systems (e.g. systems connected to the internet).

**After the Edit:** You could either make sure the variables you're going to use *have* some value (just blindly echoing a get/post var isn't the best practice) - or you could use an object to store the variables you want to output (as properties) and use `__get()` to return an empty string (or a false) when the property hasn't been set.

That would leave you with something like:

```
echo $view->something;
if($view->something){
   //stuff to do when something is set
}
```

I believe that would be similar to what a lot of template/view libraries do.

**Update**: Noticed this old(ish) answer, and thought something could be added to it. For this use case (where values may or may not be in an array), [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/array_merge) could be used:

```
$default = array('user' => false);
$params = array_merge($default, $_GET);
if($params['user']){ //safe to use, will have default value if not in $_GET

}
```

Comment: but what if he only wants to suppress errors in specific parts of the script? turning off all errors is not always desirable.

Comment: @fabio: Hiding errors in just a specific part is called "bug" ;) If you think about, that you need it, than you should really think about, that there is propably something wrong with that part.

Comment: @fabio: Its not turning off erorrs, it simply determines if errors should be printed on screen or not.

Comment: @fabio and all - updated with the PHP manual note on display errors and production systems.

Comment: @Tim Lytle: thanks for your concerns, I am definitively not using '@' again. And +1 by the way because i found your answers very informative.

Answer (score 2):

Why you want to surpress something, that will not occur, if you check the array before accessing it?

```
$something = array_key_exists('else', $_GET) ? $_GET['else'] : null;
$something = isset($_GET['else']) ? $_GET['else'] : null;
```

Your way seems to be just the solution for the lazy ones.

However, the `@`-operator is never a good idea as long as you can avoid it (and there are really very less situation, where you cant avoid it). Its also quite inperformant.

Comment: `array_key_exists` is not useful  for that. There will never be a key present with a value of NULL. It's all strings.

Comment: I completely agree that `@` is to be avoided in almost all case, but this is a perfect example of when **to** use `@`.  `$something = @ $_GET['else']` is much easier to read (imho) than the conditional expressions and produces the same result.

Comment: The performance part is actually what got me worrying about it.

Comment: It is also interesting to note that you can suppress entire expressions nested within parenthesis and so on with this '@' operator. Though I have already concluded that it is very bad practice to that and should be avoided.

Comment: Does isset run faster then array_key_exists?

Answer (score 2):

Use a general function for array accesses:

```
/**
 * Function for accessing array elements and returning a
 * default value if the element is not set or null.
 * @param string $key Name of index
 * @param array $array Reference to an array
 * @param string $default Value to return if the key is not
 *        found in the array
 * @return mixed Value of array element (if it exists) or whatever
 *        is passed for default.
 */
function element( $key, &$a, $default = '' )
{
    if( array_key_exists( $key, $a ) && !is_null( $a[$k] ) )
    {
        return $a[$key];
    }
    return $default;
}
```

Then your HTML output can look like this:

```
echo '<input type="text" name="whatever" value="'
   , element( 'whatever', $values ), '" />'
;
```

Answer (score 1):

I've said it before and am happy to say it again:

```
$else = isset($_GET['else']) ? $_GET['else'] : null;
```

Is equivalent to:

```
$else = @$_GET["else"];
```

The difference is that one is less readable due to syntactic salt for error suppression, and the other uses the intended language feature for that. Also notice how in the second case the notice (many people don't comprehend the difference to errors) can still be uncovered by custom handlers.

For all practical purposes you should use neither. Use simply:

```
$else = $_GET["else"];
```

Turn off debug notices while you don't need them.

(Practically I'm also usually using the dumb `isset()` method. But I'm using object-oriented superglobals, rather than PHP4-style $_POST and $_GET arrays, so it's just one hidden isset() and doesn't pollute my code.)

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem and while the solution is simple, you're right that it's not pretty.  Personally I like to use wrappers.  You can very easily write a simple class that implements ArrayAccess by wrapping the array passed in.  It would do the key check internally (in one place), and quietly return null when asked for a non-existent key.  The result looks something like this:

'bar'));
var_dump($arr['foo']);
var_dump($arr['zing']);
// string(3) "bar"
// NULL

?>

This may also feel more familiar to you, coming from Javascript, as you can add new functionality to the class as well, like custom sorting, or maybe filtering.